# Setting the size of a subview related to the parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

Right, so I have a class called SimpleCalculator, in the interface builder I have a button with an IBAction. When I press the button it adds a subview that contains complex functions and then animates it so it slides up from the bottom.

The issue I am having is when I run it on iPad it will always take up the full screen to show the functions, however I want it to only take up 75% of the screen as it does when I run it on iPhone.

Here is the code I have currently to do this:

```
- (IBAction)advancedButton:(id)sender {
    UIView * advancedView = advancedCalculator.view;

    [advancedView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:advancedView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    [advancedView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.25, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy method that I'd suggest you. Disable auto-layout and size class in the storyboard and try using manual method. It is very simple :) :) Let me know, if you're not clear :)

Comment: I'm not sure, would you be able to give me a bit more guidance? I understand how to disable auto layout and size class but I am a bit lost after that

Comment: Go to your storyboard and select your view controller. Go to first tab in the file inspector which is the right side of your XCode. Under interface builder document, uncheck the two checkboxes which is Use Auto-layout and Use size classes.   

Later go to file inspector, go to last before tab, and check your defined resizing and margin styles :) :)

Comment: Alright, I have tried redefining the margin styles and resizing but it does not resize at all when I am trying it on my iPad

Comment: It will work for sure... Try commenting the above code. Since, they uses the whole height and width of a device. I am damn sure that it will work.. Try selecting the width and height to be filled on the resizing screen in the file inspector :)

Comment: I tried commenting out the code which sets the frame but it then just returns to a smaller size and doesn't fill the screen on the iPad.

Comment: If you would like I can put my code onto git so you could have a look?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/pnarendran23/myown) I created a simple project by disabling auto-layout and size classes.

Comment: Can you see the link I posted?

Comment: OOPS.... I'm sorry for the late reply. I couldn't find any project on the link that you sent

Comment: I just added you as a collaborator so you should be able to see it now